# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am working on Xamarin.Forms in Android project I am getting error.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of
>   $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing
>   'java.exe -Xmx4G -jar
>   C:\android-sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\lib\dx.jar --dex
>   --no-strict --multi-dex --main-dex-list=obj\Debug\90\multidex.keep --output obj\Debug\90\android\bin D:\Arvind.ch\SIS\SIS_Product\SIS-Global-Dev\edTheSISApp\edTheSIS\edTheSIS\edTheSIS.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\bin\classes.zip
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.jar"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar"
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\28\jl\android.arch.core.common.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\29\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\30\jl\android.arch.lifecycle.common.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\31\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\32\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\33\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\34\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\35\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\36\jl\com.android.support.support-annotations.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\37\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\38\jl\com.android.support.collections.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\39\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\40\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\41\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\42\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\43\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\44\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\45\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\46\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\47\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\48\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\49\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\5\jl\formsviewgroup.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\50\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\51\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\52\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\53\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\54\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\55\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\56\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\57\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\58\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\59\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\60\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\61\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\62\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\63\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\64\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\65\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\66\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\68\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\69\jl\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\70\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\75\jl\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\90\lp\76\jl\classes.jar'    SIS.Android

This is built output

```
 No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
1>  5 errors; aborting
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2610,3): error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -Xmx4G -jar C:\android-sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\\lib\dx.jar --dex --no-strict --multi-dex --main-dex-list=obj\Debug\90\multidex.keep --output obj\Debug\90\android\bin D:\Arvind.ch\SIS\SIS_Product\SIS-Global-Dev\edTheSISApp\edTheSIS\edTheSIS\edTheSIS.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\bin\classes.zip "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\mono.android.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar" obj\Debug\90\lp\28\jl\android.arch.core.common.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\29\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\30\jl\android.arch.lifecycle.common.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\31\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\32\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\33\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\34\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\35\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\36\jl\com.android.support.support-annotations.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\37\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\38\jl\com.android.support.collections.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\39\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\40\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\41\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\42\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\43\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\44\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\45\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\46\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\47\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\48\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\49\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\5\jl\formsviewgroup.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\50\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\51\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\52\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\53\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\54\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\55\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\56\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\57\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\58\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\59\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\60\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\61\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\62\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\63\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\64\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\65\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\66\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\68\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\69\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\70\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\75\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\90\lp\76\jl\classes.jar'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```